# Python: Setup.py doesn't copy code to site-packages

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, setup.py

I wrote my own python package and when I try to install with:

```
python setup.py install
```

It installs the package and puts an *egg* file in site-packages folder, but the code stays in the original folder (on my desktop) instead of moving to site-packages too.
The setup.py script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup
from mypackage import __version__

setup(
    name  =  'mypackage',
    packages = ['mypackage'],
    version = __version__
)
```

The folder of the package looks like this:

```
setup.py
mypackage/
         __init__.py
         mymodule.py
```

How can I get it to copy the package to site-package like it normally does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need. That egg file is a [single file importable distribution format](https://wiki.python.org/moin/egg) containing your code. You should be able to import it as is.